# Insert column data to file from another files

Tags: python, bash

I need to paste several columns one after another from other files to my new file like this:

file 1

```
4 5    
4 6    
2 3
```

file 2

```
3 6
8 6
2 6
```

result file

```
#some note
4 5   3 6
4 6   8 6
2 3   2 6
```

Please help me, how to paste it after text line #some note, for example, on the third line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I mean, first two columns from file 1, and other two from file 2

Comment: Check `paste` examples on net.

Comment: what is #some note? How are you getting it?

Comment: I want to paste this data after a text, like note in file...

Answer (score 0):

This is what does `paste` command. See `man paste`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk:

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR] (a[FNR]==""?"":OFS) $0}END{print "#some note";for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]}' file1 file2 file2
#some note
4 5 3 6 3 6
4 6 8 6 8 6
2 3 2 6 2 6
```

Explained:

```
awk '
{
    a[FNR]=a[FNR] (a[FNR]==""?"":OFS) $0  # gather data to a hash keyed on FNR
}
END {                                     # after all hashing
    print "#some note"                    # first, print the note
    for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)                   # and print the records from the hash
        print a[i]}
' file1 file2 file2
```

Comment: What if I need to add tab between columns?

Comment: Atm `OFS` (_output field separator_) is used to separate the column pairs (`4 5 OFS 3 6`) from the files ie. each row or record in a file is considered a string. By default the `OFS` is a space, so you could either redefine the `OFS` to a tab (`BEGIN{OFS="\t"}` or `awk -v OFS='\t'`) or replace the `OFS` in the code with `"\t"`. If you want to separate the column in the file with a tab, then the code needs to change a bit more.